# Give unique group ID by condition in other columns

Tags: r, interaction

I would like to group the rows into groups giving them a unique `group ID` in a new column `group`. The rows should be given the same ID if `RNAClass` and `V1` is simlar and `diff` is less than 10000. E.g. all rows with rRNA and chr1 and diff < 10000 is given ID1.

I though if using `interaction`

```
transform(input, group_ID = as.numeric(interaction(RNAClass, V1, drop=TRUE)))
```

Input:

```
   RNAClass    V1       diff
21     rRNA  chr8        122
33     rRNA  chr1       1140
45     rRNA  chr1       1313
68     rRNA  chr8       2222
72     tRNA  chr9       9207
80     tRNA  chr9       5111
72     tRNA  chr9     492407
80     tRNA  chr9      54111
```

Output:

```
   RNAClass    V1       diff    group
21     rRNA  chr8        122    ID1
33     rRNA  chr1       1140    ID2
45     rRNA  chr1       1313    ID2
68     rRNA  chr8       2222    ID1
72     tRNA  chr9       9207    ID3
80     tRNA  chr9       5111    ID3
72     tRNA  chr9     492407    ID4
80     tRNA  chr9       5111    ID3
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` option would be to create a logical index 'i1' based on the 'diff' column, `paste` the 'RNAClass', and 'V1' ('str1'), change the elements in 'str1' based on 'i1' to make it a unique string.  Convert the 'str1' to `factor` with `levels` specified as `unique` values of 'str1', coerce to `integer` and `paste` with 'ID'

```
i1 <- input$diff >= 10000
str1 <- with(input, paste(RNAClass, V1))
str1[i1] <- paste0(str1[i1], seq_len(sum(i1)))
input$group <- paste0("ID", as.integer(factor(str1, levels = unique(str1))))
input$group
#[1] "ID1" "ID2" "ID2" "ID1" "ID3" "ID3" "ID4" "ID3"
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
input %>%
  mutate(group = paste0(RNAClass, V1,  as.integer(diff> 10000)),
         group = paste0("ID", as.integer(factor(group, levels = unique(group)))))
```

NOTE: The last element showed in the 'diff' is taken as '5111' and not '54111'

Comment: I think you need to change `as.integer(diff> 10000)` to 100,000 instead of 10,000.

Comment: @tyluRp  Thanks, but the OP's condition is 10,000.

Comment: Crap, my mistake

Comment: @tyluRp  No problem,  I also got confused earlier based on the numbers